# Ionic navigation controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to have three types of navigation in my Ionic app. Is there anything that I can do to minimize my code?
Main problem: All three navigation has the same side menu, but different header navigation.
My code for first navigation:

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-traveler">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-title class="heder-tabs">
        <div class="heder-avatar">
          <a >
            <img src="img/default-avatar.png">
          </a>
          <div class="karma-box-heder">1243</div>
        </div>
        <span><a >Travel</a></span>
        <span><a >Location</a></span>
        <span><a >Networking</a></span>
      </ion-nav-title>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view class="has-header"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>


  <ion-side-menu side="right" class="has-header-nav">
    <ion-content class="navigation-bg-color">
      <ion-list class="app-right-navigation">
         <ion-item class="side-navigation-user sidenav-box" menu-close href="">
           <div class="user-nav">
            <div class="user-sidenav-logo">
              <img src="img/default-avatar.png">
              <div class="karma-box">1243</div>
            </div>
            <div class="first-three-nav-choice">User Name</div>
          </div>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="side-navigation-pinko sidenav-box" menu-close href="">
          <div class="pinko-nav">
            <div class="pinko-sidenav-logo">
              <img src="img/pro4travel-logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="first-three-nav-choice">Pinko</div>
          </div>  
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="side-navigation-club sidenav-box" menu-close href="">
          <div class="club-nav">
            <div class="club-sidenav-logo">
              <img src="img/app4travel-logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="first-three-nav-choice">Club</div>
          </div>  
        </ion-item> 
        <ion-item class="other-nav-text" menu-close href="">
          <div class="icon-navigation"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="text-nav-list">My Agency</div>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="other-nav-text" menu-close href="">
          <div class="icon-navigation"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="text-nav-list">My Karma</div>
          
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="other-nav-text" menu-close href="">
          <div class="icon-navigation"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="text-nav-list">Notification</div>
          
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="other-nav-text" menu-close href="">
          <div class="icon-navigation"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="text-nav-list">Profile</div>
        </ion-item>
         <ion-item class="other-nav-text" menu-close href="">
          <div class="icon-navigation"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="text-nav-list">Settings</div>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="other-nav-text" menu-close href="">
          <div class="icon-navigation"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="text-nav-list">Log out</div>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

So Box1 on picture is the box that containts my Header navigation(navigation that needs to be diffrent on other two navigation)
And Box2 on picture is box thats stays the same.
Aslo here is picture how to looks in my app:
[image]

So depent on what page is the box1 need to be changed and box2 needs to stay the same.

Comment: ng-repeat with a properly formed array of items?

Comment: [{icon: 'user', state: 'index', text: 'Home'}] ? Loop that and you can create your menu's items.

Comment: Please don't post picture of your code. It is unreadable. Post directly the code with 4 spaces on each line to format

Comment: I would add this to e666 comment : "Please don't post picture of your code. It is unreadable **and untestable** [...]".

Comment: @e666 I understand, its not picture now

Comment: Please, don't add again Ionic2 tag... It is not an Ionic2 code...